# NEXT AUTH + Firebase Cannot import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, next.js, next-auth

So we have a firebase config file:

```
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const firebaseStore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
```

and NEXT AUTH [...nextauth].ts

```
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { firebaseConfig } from "../../../config/firebase";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_WEB_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter(firebaseConfig),
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

The problem is that i'm always facing an error

```
Error - H:\JS\ktest\node_modules\@next-auth\firebase-adapter\dist\index.js:1
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at @next-auth/firebase-adapter (H:\JS\ktest\.next\server\pages\api\auth\[...nextauth].js:22:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (H:\JS\ktest\.next\server\webpack-api-runtime.js:33:42)
```

I tried changing package.json and tsconfig with "type":"module" and etc but i causes more errors and that shouldn't be a fix for this issue.

I'm struggling for some time with this issue and can't find any answers online anymore, i feel like stackoverflow is my last hope.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 'firebase-adapter' inside code has problem with module and CommonJS.
so, I modifying file directly for solved this problem. (import -> require)

in your case
'H:\JS\ktest\node_modules@next-auth\firebase-adapter\dist\index.js' and
'H:\JS\ktest\node_modules@next-auth\firebase-adapter\dist\converter.js'

index.js ->

```
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase/app");
const { addDoc, collection, deleteDoc, doc, getDoc, getDocs, getFirestore, limit, query, runTransaction, setDoc, where, connectFirestoreEmulator, } = require("firebase/firestore");
const { getConverter } = require("./converter");
module.exports.FirestoreAdapter = ({ emulator, ...firebaseOptions }) => {
```

coverter.js ->

```
const { Timestamp } = require("firebase/firestore");
const isTimestamp = (value) => typeof value === "object" && value !== null && value instanceof Timestamp;
module.exports.getConverter = (options) => ({
```

like this way.